# Define function receiver or rather pass struct pointer in argument?

Tags: go

Coming from years of Java, I recently picked up Golang and I wondered how the somewhat different paradigm affects common practices. Most importantly: If I define a struct and I want to have a function which works on that struct (aka a method), do I define the function as "belonging" to the struct or do I rather pass the pointer to that struct in an own function body?
In other terms:

`func (c *Component) initState()`

or

`func initState(c *Component)`

Does either one have advantage over the other (other than e.g. readability for Java users or semantic clarity), as there are no real object/class concepts in Golang? I'd mostly go for the first alternative, but my view may be biased by working in an object-oriented world for some time, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Methods allow you to implement interfaces, functions don't.

Comment: The first defines a "method" and the second is a "function" and not  a method! Methods allow a type to satisfy interfaces, functions don't.

Comment: One potentially useful side effect of methods is that, since they are bound to the receiver's type, it is easier to avoid naming collision. For example you can have `func (T1) F()` and `func (T2) F()` in the same package, while `func F(T1)` and `func F(T2)` in the same package will cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is *mostly* semantic: is `initState` a *behavior of* `Component`, or is it a function *operating on* `Component`?

There is one syntactic difference, and that is that only a method (a function with a receiver) can satisfy an interface. If that is not relevant to your case, then follow the semantic distinction.

Comment: Was not aware of interfaces at this point, thanks for clarification!